# Stream in like box not "complete"

Tags: stream, facebook-likebox

I have created a like box, working fine. Question: By now, only posts from myself are shown in the like box stream on my [page](http://www.ehcb-spirit.ch/elite-facebook.php), but posts from other users are not shown, like the one of Theo Schmid on the [fan page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Elite-EHC-Biel-Bienne-Spirit/460498567325498).

Is there any possibility to show all posts? Thanks for any help :-)